# Eclipse surround with quotes and other blocks

Tags: java, eclipse

I find myself wanting to highlight a string in eclipse and double or single quoting it.  I can't seem to find a shortcut for it.  In textmate for example if i highlight a string and type either a ' or a " the string will be surrounded with them.  The same should work with ) and } i think as well.

I've added a code template for doing it but it doesn't ever appear in the menu and there doesn't seem to be a way to create shortcuts for it either.  Note that this should be entirely keyboard driven and not involve any secondary menus, that's my goal anyway.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Go to ***Java > Editor > Templates*** and add a **new template**, e. g. called **`quote`**, as follows:

```
 "${word_selection}"${cursor}
```

Then, in the editor, write a text you want to quote, **select it**, press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>**, type **`quote`** and hit **<kbd>Return</kbd>**. The highlighted text should be quoted now.

If you don't get template proposals when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, make sure you have them checked in *Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced*.

Just tried it and it works for me!

Comment: You could also call it " and that way its even closer to what the OP asked! (ie. ctrl + space then " + enter)

Comment: True, but now you have to hit Return twice in order for the template to apply. But if you call it "" (two double quotes) it works :)

Comment: Really? I tried it with MyEclipse for Spring and I only had to hit Return once for it to apply. Although you do have to be sort of quick, if you wait too long it will just place a quote in place of the string :P

Comment: This works but doesn't really meet the "secondary menus" part. Ideally I'd like to be able to type ctrl+shift+" (or similar) and that's it

Comment: @Mike Yep, when I select the " from the templates, two quotes are displayed instead of the original text. When I hit Return for the first time, the cursor skips after the second quote and when I hit it for the second time, the quotes get actually replaced by the whole quoted string.