# Wrap selection with parenthesis in Eclipse Mars.1

Tags: eclipse

Usually I use Atom, Sublime Text, Tex Studio or an editor from Jetbrains. There I can select text and when I press quote or open parenthesis or braces, my selection is wrapped with quotes resp. parenthesis resp. braces. In Eclipse Mars.1 JEE this doesn't work and I can't find a setting for this. Is it possible in Eclipse Mars.1 JEE or at least in a newer Eclipse version?

I use Eclipse with JEE, CDT and other project types.

Comment: In the Eclipse Java editor there are so-called _[Quick Assists](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-quickfix-assist.htm)_ (Ctrl+1) to surround an expression or a lambda parameter with parenthesis (without the need to select it). In a JetBrain editor, if you want to replace a selection with an opening parenthesis, do you have to delete the selection first?

Comment: Yes, when this setting is active, you have to delete the selection otherwise the selection will be wrapped in quotes. I will try it on monday.

Comment: I tried it out with Eclipse Oxygen.1 JEE but when I select some text and press CTRL+1 I get some options to choose but no option to surround my selection with quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse surround with quotes and other blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622609/eclipse-surround-with-quotes-and-other-blocks)