# Eclipse - Enclose selection instead of replacing

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, when i select part of a text and press any key, the whole selection is replaced.
I would like to know how to make it, instead of replacing the text, add the key pressed to both ends of the selection, as it happens on visual studio code.

Example:

`System.out.println(HelloWorld);`

Select Hello World

`System.out.println(`**HelloWorld**`);`

Then press the **"** button. The code will turn to

`System.out.println(");`

Can i config the IDE so it will instead change it to

`System.out.println("HelloWorld");`

There is a already answered question like this one, but considering that one as 7 years and a lot of version old, and also considering that the answer on that one is kind of a work around, i would like to know if there's any new plugin or configuration that make it work better

Comment: I am sorry can you please give an example?

Comment: Consider the code: 
`System.out.println(HelloWorld);`
I select the "Hello world" and press the " button, it will replace the text with a " instead of making it be `System.out.println("HelloWorld");`.
Can i change the configuration so it does't replace the selected text?

Comment: thanks for the example I am reading it

Comment: sorry I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse surround with quotes and other blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622609/eclipse-surround-with-quotes-and-other-blocks)

Comment: Well, it really seens as duplicated, but that answer is 7 years old, a lot of new versions came, and the solution displayed there is more like a work around

Comment: smart keys on intellij ended up solving this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I gather, you are wanting to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5622708/2112501)?

> Go to ***Java > Editor > Templates*** and add a **new template**, e. g. called **`quote`**, as follows:
>
> ```
> "${word_selection}"${cursor}
> ```
>
> Then, in the editor, write a text you want to quote, **select it**, press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>**, type **`quote`** and hit **<kbd>Return</kbd>**. The highlighted text should be quoted now.
>
> If you don't get template proposals when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, make sure you have them checked in *Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced*.
>
> Just tried it and it works for me!

You can use this method for other things, like `(${word_selection})${cursor}` for parenthesis or `'${word_selection}'${cursor}` for single quote.

Comment: It is a good answer, i'll mark this as the accepted answer if no other appear, but i would prefer eclipse to work like other code editors and simply not replace the text when selecting and pressing a key

Comment: @PedroGuilhermeBueno This is as close as you are going to get with Eclipse. They have not implemented a was, to my knowledge, to do things automagicly like other IDEs.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer, i will try looking on some plugins maybe. I'll give it some more time and then select your answer as the accepted one

Comment: this with smart keys fixed my problem